# Creating a PPA containing a Node.js script

Tags: ppa, nodejs

I've asked this on StackOverflow proper and while I hate to feel like I'm spamming questions, I wonder if this might be the more appropriate place to get a good answer.

I've got this [very simple NPM package](https://github.com/Batterii/graphql-playground-server) that I'd like to have installed as a service on my company's development machines. I'd like to make this service available in the package managers that are commonly used on each OS used by our team, so that I don't have to ask people to screw around with file system permissions, service managers, and so forth.

I found [this](https://docs.brew.sh/Node-for-Formula-Authors) for Homebrew which was super helpful in getting [this tap](https://github.com/Batterii/homebrew-graphql-playground-server) together, but I've been completely unable to find anything about how to set up a similar PPA for installing on Ubuntu. Ultimately, it seems like it just needs to copy my node script and its `node_modules` folder into a subfolder in `/usr/share`, create a system user specifically for running this service, and create a Unit file for `systemd` to start and stop the service as this user. I'm able to put all this stuff in place manually with relative ease, but it would be nice to be able to tell the other developers at my company that they can just add a PPA and run `sudo apt install graphql-playground-server`.

I've found [node-deb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-deb) which creates a `.deb` package that I can install with `dpkg` just fine, but PPA's do not allow uploading of pre-built `.deb` packages. So it seems that I need to create something *like* node-deb that will produce something I can actually upload to a PPA with `dput`.

Unfortunately, I have found [this documentation](https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html) to be **incredibly confusing** and I've spent the better part of the past two days tearing my hair out trying to make any progress at all. It kind of blows my mind that I can't seem to find a more straightforward guide to doing this.

Any help would be appreciated. I realize I am no Ubuntu expert by any means, so I'm well aware this could be a very stupid question with an easy answer somewhere on the web, so I'd be happy to be pointed in the right direction if so. :)

I am using Linux Mint 19.3 with the Cinnamon desktop.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

If the term "PPA" means a real Launchpad-hosted PPA, you must host the source code on Launchpad and use Launchpad's builder.

Alternately, you can host your own third-party repository (different from a PPA), and you can manage it however you like. [Debian instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Setup)

If your package may have wider appear, you can [contribute it to Debian](http://mentors.debian.net), where it will get merged into furture releases of Ubuntu. Then you don't need a separate repository at all.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking to do a real Launchpad-hosted PPA. Obviously I don't need that if I'm only sharing this with my organization, but I'm also trying to do this as a way of learning more about this ecosystem. I may go down the third party repository route, though, if this proves too challenging.

Comment: Advice: To me, it not an either/or decision. It's a "*I'll do this in 2020, but I'll do the other in 2021*" set of flexible alternatives. Some need will change, or another need will come along, and you'll have the tools in place to meet that change easily.